# Can't open lucene index (Java heap space)

Tags: lucene, solr, out-of-memory, luke

I want to grab some data from lucene index file. But I can't read it.

I try to use `Luke`, but it always crashes with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Note `-Xmx` can't help me. I try -Xmx512, -Xmx1024 and even -Xmx2048.

I try to use `Solr` also, but gets `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` too.

Any ideas how I can extract some data from Lucene?

P. S. I use lucene 2.3.0. My index file is 1.8 Gb size.

Comment: btw: an update of your lucene version is highly recommended ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create my own simple lucene client, based on `org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher`. And grab data that I want.

Answer (score 0):

What size is the data you are trying to fetch? Maybe the result set is too large to handle?

Comment: I can't even start Luke or Solr with my database.

Comment: You probably have to use a Luke version that can read older indexes. What Luke version are you using?

Here are the Luke versions: http://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/list

And here an interesting topic: http://code.google.com/p/luke/issues/detail?id=40

Comment: The same sh*t with `Luke 1.0.1`  (It supports Lucene 2.3.0 as i can see in: http://code.google.com/p/luke/wiki/Compatibility ). I started it as: `java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m lukeall-1.0.1.jar`